# How to insert an element with the same indent as the previous one

Tags: xml, xslt

Assume the following xml:

```
<def>
  <config>
        <a>foo</a>
  </config>
</def>
```

i want to insert another config "b". I need to preserve the current formating. Thus i think i have to care about the indentation of "b" for myself? What i am trying to achieve is the following result:

```
<def>
  <config>
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>bar</b>
  </config>
</def>
```

Please note that there are different sizes of indent. So the newly created element should align with the previous one. In case that there is no previous element on the same level, the indent should be the parent's indent plus 2.

Comment: Remember that indentation is actually a whitespace text node in XML. If you want indentation between <a> and <b> insert a text node containing carriage return and the appropriate spaces or tabs. Or just use the appropriate xsl:output settings to request automatic indentation by depth. But be aware that some applications DO care about that content, and changing indentation may change how they interpret the document.

Comment: @keshlam: Yes, i need to keep the indentation, so xsl:output is not an option. My problem is: How to detect the 'appropriate spaces'? I need to remember the text node between <config> and <a> and just to repeat it before <b>. While this may look trivial for an xsl expert, it does not for me ;-)

Comment: "*Please note that there are different sizes of indent.*" Why is the size of the indent (or the indent itself) important? In XML, white space is considered insignificant unless expressly declared otherwise - see: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Whitespace is indeed insignificant for a system. But not for a human eye... ;-)

Comment: @Henning IMHO, the human eye is easily satisfied by the default automatic indenting - which applies equal indent amount for each level.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Someone has written that xml file. It has grown over time. And maybe the current strange indentation, blank lines, comments were by intent. An automatic script should not distort this. It should try to keep the current format.

Comment: @Henning That's a very weak reason to keep unreasonable indentation in my opinion. Indendation should not have any meaning in XML, as a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this should make any difference but as an exercise, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config/*[last()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::text()[1]"/>
    <b>bar</b>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: With Saxon 6.5.5, the output has empty lines in between the elements and the indent is not preserved. But it works without `indent="yes"` and with `omit-xml-declaration="yes"`.

Comment: Tested with xsltproc. Works perfect. Thank you very much! Again i am impressed how easy the solution looks like.